# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: spring, http, wildfly

Делаю проект на Spring. В контроллере использую аннотацию @Controller, т.е. формирую простые jsp-страницы...
На tomcat приложение работает, HTTP-методы Get и Post работают хорошо. Делаю деплой на WildFly (11 версия) . Там при попытке навигации по страницам или перезагрузки страницы (redirect:/), или отправки формы по submit - выпадает ошибка "**HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL**". Подскажите что нужно сделать, чтобы всё заработало?

Контроллер прост до ужаса:

```
@Controller
public class JmsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/jms", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String weatherData(Model model, @RequestBody String city) throws IOException {
        // Получить ответ с yahoo.weather.com
        Location weatherInCity = jmsService.loadByCity(city);
        // Сформировать JMS
        jmsService.sendMessage(weatherInCity);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

jsp лежит в webapp/index.jsp. Сабмит пишу так:

```
<form role="form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jms"  method="POST">
```

В application.properties пишу следующее:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Стартую страницу так:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: "пальцем в небо" - предполагаю, что это не касается вашего кода, а скорее - вопрос настройки сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Огромное спасибо всем, кто не остался равнодушным и попытался помочь! Нашёл проблему. Уверен, что  решение сможет помочь кому-то ещё такому же неопытному, как  и я. В общем изменил старт программы с

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

на

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Короче говоря, надо было унаследоваться от SpringBootServletInitializer  и переопределить метод configure